# How to make a switch statement to keep repeating in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm looking for my menu to allow the user to enter another menu otion after they've already selected one but i'm not sure how to get it to do this. I've tried a while loop but it just keeps repeating and doesnt stop.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MainMenu
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int userChoice;

            userChoice = menu();
        }

    private static int menu()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Choose an Option");
        System.out.println("1 - DISPLAY THE UN-SHUFFLED DECK");
        System.out.println("2 - PERFORM RANDOM SHUFFLE");
        System.out.println("3 - REVEAL THE CARD AT THE TOP OF THE DECK");
        System.out.println("4 - EXIT");

        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean quit = false;
        do{
            System.out.println("Choose an option");

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("\n1 - DISPLAY THE UN-SHUFFLED DECK\n");
                    // call method
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("\n2 - PERFORM RANDOM SHUFFLE\n");
                    Deck.shuffleDeck();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\n3 - REVEAL THE CARD AT THE TOP OF THE DECK\n");
                    Deck.findTop();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("\nYou have successfully exited the program");
                    // exit the program
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("\nInvalid Option");
                    break;
            }
            While (!quit);
            return choice;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd say a `while` loop is the way to go. Currently there isn't any `while` in your code so we can't tell you why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: "I've tried a while loop". Ok. How? Show us that attempt, because some kind of loop is definitely the right way to solve it. Show us what you attempted and we can tell you why it didn't do what you hoped.

Comment: What is wrong with an infinite while loop? Why can't you use that if you want to loop around that switch statement indefinitely?

Comment: `switch` is the wrong statement for that. You need a loop. Maybe you're looking for a `for` loop that calls your `menu()` method a few times?

Comment: You asked the very same question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411268/how-to-make-a-switch-statement-to-keep-continuing-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536206/do-while-loop-to-show-a-menu i guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: Your while loop should probably be outside of the `menu` function. Assuming this is a turn-based game, a simple `while(true){ userChoice = menu(); }` in `main` would be ok, as `menu` takes care of exiting itself..

Comment: I've edited my code to show the while loop that i had tried